# Use For to group maps as one map?

Tags: clojure, etl

The code I have mostly works but the data isn't in the desired format.

It produces

```
({"apples" {price 2}}
 {"pears"  {price 4}})
```

I'd like to be be grouped as one map

```
{"apples" {price 2}
 "pears"  {price 4}}
```

This is the code

```
(defn summarize-many-maps-with-keyname [ms]
  (for [m ms]
    {(first (keys m))
     (summarize-one (first (vals m)))}))
```

Is there some way to tell `for` to group them inside a single map? If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: In addition to the answer, I would say that it might be better to change your initial code to produce a single map in the first place. It also seems that you simply want to apply a function to all values in a map - for that, there's `update-vals`.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov My input is a vector of maps. I want to create a summary by summing the values of the keys. So the output of `summarize-one` is a map with several kvs.

Comment: could you add sample input/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about merging the list of maps?

```
(apply merge {} ms)
```

or the same thing with reduce:

```
(reduce into {} ms)
```

Or, if you insist on using `for` macro, you can just go through the list of maps and also each entry of each map and dump them into a new map:

```
(into {} (for [m ms
               entry m]
           entry))
```

Comment: `into` is already an optimized `reduce conj`.  If you don't want to use
`merge` (which I think OP is actually looking for here), then
I'd rather use `(into {} cat ms)` instead of `(reduce into ,,,)`.

Comment: You don't even need `(into {} cat ms)`. `conj`ing two maps merges them, so just `(into {} ms)` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This works beautifully:

```
(into {} '({"apples" {:price 2}} {"pears"  {:price 4}}))
;;=>{"apples" {:price 2}, "pears" {:price 4}}
```

Comment: Credit where it's due: @amalloy commented the answer before me

Answer (score 0):

`for` lets you *nest* loops which is quite useful for operations that flatten datastructures in various ways:

```
(defn regroup-with-for [ms]
  (into {}
        (for [m ms
              kv-pair m]
          kv-pair)))

(regroup-with-for '({"apples" {price 2}}
                    {"pears"  {price 4}}))
;; => {"apples" {price 2}, "pears" {price 4}}
```

In the outer loop, we visit every item `m` inside `ms`. In the inner loop, we visit every key-value pair `kv-pair` in `m`. The `for` form evaluates to a sequence of key-value pairs that we put inside an empty map using `into`.

Here is another approach with three nested loops, also using `for`:

```
(defn regroup-with-for [ms]
  (apply hash-map
         (for [m ms
               kv-pair m
               x kv-pair]
           x)))

(regroup-with-for '({"apples" {price 2}}
                    {"pears"  {price 4}}))
;; => {"apples" {price 2}, "pears" {price 4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all good. Due to my perception on the ambiguity between `merge` and `into`, I wrote a simpler (IMHO) function [named glue](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.03.17d/api/tupelo.core#glue). The docs give the intended use case:

```
  Glues together like collections:

       (glue [1 2] [3 4] [5 6])                -> [1 2 3 4 5 6]
       (glue {:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3})             -> {:a 1 :c 3 :b 2}
       (glue #{1 2} #{3 4} #{6 5})             -> #{1 2 6 5 3 4}
       (glue \"I\" \" like \" \\a \" nap!\" )  -> \"I like a nap!\"

  If you want to convert to a sorted set or map, just put an empty one first:

       (glue (sorted-map) {:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3})      -> {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
       (glue (sorted-set) #{1 2} #{3 4} #{6 5})      -> #{1 2 3 4 5 6}

   If there are duplicate keys when using glue for maps or sets, then \"the last one wins\":

       (glue {:band :VanHalen :singer :Dave}  {:singer :Sammy})
```

For your problem we have

```
  (is= (apply glue
         '({"apples" {price 2}}
           {"pears" {price 4}}
           {"oranges" {price 5}}))
    {"apples"  {price 2}
     "oranges" {price 5}
     "pears"   {price 4}})
```

The part with `apply` tells the function that we are giving all of the arguments in a single sequence, instead of having 3 separate args.

The [source code](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/v23.03.17d/src/tupelo/core.cljc#L1381) is straightforward.  It uses both `(reduce conj ...)` and `(reduce into ...)` for all common data types.

Comment: This only works if there are exactly two maps, in which case you might as well just use `(merge a b)` or `(into a b)`. For lists of any other size this is no good.

Comment: You are correct, I am out of practice using `into`.  It does work for N maps with `tupelo.core/glue`.

Comment: Corrected the answer.